# UI not updating after ajax fetch

Tags: angularjs, ajax, api

I have this code for a restaurant app:

```
    // Select date and load resources
    $scope.selectDate = function (date) {
        $scope.dateInActiveSelection = date;
        loadMenuFor(date);
    };

    // Load daily menu for given date.
    function loadMenuFor (date) {
        DataApi.dailyMenu(date, function (response) {
            console.log('Loaded menu for ' + date.toString());
            $scope.menuItems = $scope.originalMenuItems = response.data;
        });
    }
```

I am fetching new menu for every day the user selects with this method:

```
    // Select date and load resources
    $scope.selectDate = function (date) {
        $scope.dateInActiveSelection = date;
        loadMenuFor(date);
    };
```

But the UI isn't updating. I have one `{{ menuItems.length }}` displayed and another `ng-repeat` neither of which are getting updated.

I tried $scope.$apply() as mentioned in other answers but I get a in-progress error, even when I try it inside a $timeout.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: You can put a log inside DateApi call back function to see if you are getting the data from the server.

Comment: Please show us your view, and make sure that your $timeout was wrapping only the assignment of the data `$timeout(function() { $scope.menuItems = $scope.originalMenuItems = response.data; });`

Comment: @GaneshKumar I did and I am getting the data. The model is also getting updated as per log but its not able to updated the UI.

Comment: Then, I think you should post the HTML code as well.

Comment: I found out the problem. There were two elements with the asking for the same controller. One was the date chooser element and another was the one with the item listing. So, whenever I was choosing the date, the scope was getting changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. There were two elements with the asking for the same controller. One was the date chooser element and another was the one with the item listing. So, whenever I was choosing the date, the scope was getting changed.